# Solaris + sed: вывести строку между тегами

Tags: sed

Добрый день!
Необходимо получить текст строки между двумя тегами.

Ниже то, что получаю после grep:

```
xxx@yyy> cat bsgExport.xml | grep "UtranCell=" | grep "iubLinkUtranCell"
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
```

Далее мне нужно получить текст между

```
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>
```

и `</un:iubLinkUtranCell>`.

Добавляю фильтр в sed, но получаю строку без изменений:

```
xxx@yyy> cat bsgExport.xml | grep "UtranCell=" | grep "iubLinkUtranCell" | sed 's/<un:iubLinkUtranCell>\(.*\)<\/un:iubLinkUtranCell>)/\1/'
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
<un:iubLinkUtranCell>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=BLABLABLA,MeContext=BLABLABLA,ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PURUMPURUM</un:iubLinkUtranCell>
```

Подскажите, что некорректно в фильтре sed?
Из особенностей то, что OS - solaris.

[UPD]: невнимательность - порок.
Ошибка была в символе ) перед /\1/.

```
sed 's/<un:iubLinkUtranCell>\(.*\)<\/un:iubLinkUtranCell>)/\1/'
```

После того, как заменил на

```
sed 's/<un:iubLinkUtranCell>\(.*\)<\/un:iubLinkUtranCell>/\1/'
```

все заработало как нужно!

Comment: Опубликуйте решение как ответ и "примите" его (зеленая галка слева).

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в символе `)` перед `/\1/`

Ошибочная строка:

```
sed 's/<un:iubLinkUtranCell>\(.*\)<\/un:iubLinkUtranCell>)/\1/'
```

После того, как был удален символ `)`получена рабочая строка:

```
sed 's/<un:iubLinkUtranCell>\(.*\)<\/un:iubLinkUtranCell>/\1/'
```

Все заработает как нужно!